# 'What of' concluded with a period?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

> 2.83. ... We have seen that the general rule is that displaying goods in shops only constitutes an invitation to treat, although there are good reasons
>   for taking a different approach (paras 2.22–2.23). However, **what of** a typical
>   website that allows the customer to select the item, enter his payment details and
>   seemingly conclude the agreement online. ♦ In this situation, then (absent the terms
>   and conditions of the site providing to the contrary) it is suggested that it is clear
>   that a contract has been concluded (see Christensen (2001) and Phang (2005)).

Based on my [other question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/186170/50720),  **what of** is a question clause (Is the right term?), right? So why a period, and NOT a question mark, where I've placed a  diamond?

Source: p 39 , *The Law of Contract*, 5 ed (2012), by O’Sullivan and Hilliard

Comment: Yes, I think a question mark would be more appropriate there.

Comment: The matter ***what of*** you are talking does not require any question mark! :P [*You see 'that' there in the sentence in concern?]

Comment: @MaulikV: I see no _that_ in the sentence. I also don't see the relevance. What of that missing _that_? Do you mean the question mark depends on the presence of _that_?

Comment: @oerkelens yes, I misread it. I was just belting along while commenting! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the full stop (period) is a mistake. "What of" is a question, even if sometimes presents as a rhetorical question. This opinion appears to be confirmed by the explanations given in the dictionary comments on the expression in your other question:

"what of 1. formal *how does that affect (someone or something)*
 2. *why does (something) matter*"

The words I have italicised are clearly questions.